# Global variables in nested components in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

I have nested component. Component **Map** for getting Google Map, and component for contain markers in this map. **Marker** inside **Map**

window.google variable available in **Map** component, but it undefined inside **Marker** comopnent.

**Map:**

```
import React from 'react'
import { Marker } from './Marker'
class Map extends React.Component {
  getGoogleMaps() {
        const script = document.createElement("script");
        const API = 'AIzaS';
        script.src = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${API}&v=3&callback=initMap`;
        script.async = true;
        script.defer = true;
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getGoogleMaps()
    window.initMap = () => {
      var map = new window.google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 15,
        center: {lat: 40.6947591, lng: -73.9950086},
        mapTypeControl: false
      })
      window.map = this.map
      console.log('<Map/> google:',window.google);
    }
   }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div id="map" ></div>
        <Marker/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export { Map }
```

**:**

```
 import React from 'react'
    class Marker extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return(
          <div>
            {console.log('<Marker/> google:',window.google)}
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
    export { Marker }
```

So .... Why global variable **window.google** is good inside **Map** component and  undefined in **Marker** ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are checking some wrong place as I have used same to same your code in Plunker, I can access both the place `window.google` variable, please check below mentioned plunk for your reference.

[Check Here](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/1woHuSuBuJkJebPK?open=Hello.js&deferRun=1&preview)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's because method `getGoogleMaps()` is async and you call it in componentDidMount. You renders Marker before Google Maps script has been loaded.

For example you can use isLoading state.

```
class ... {
  state = {
    isLoading: true
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getGoogleMaps()
    window.initMap = () => {
      ...
      window.map = this.map;
      //update state here
      console.log('<Map/> google:',window.google);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.isLoading 
    ? <div>loading...</div>
    : (
      <div>
        <div id="map" ></div>
        <Marker/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```